# create-react-app and Express in production

Tags: reactjs, express, production

I used create-react-app and express generator to build my app with some basic redux. I am trying to deploy the app now but because I have two server running, I need to combine them into one.

The app ran no problem locally until I added this script into my main express JS file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
   response.sendFile('../client/build/index.html', {global: root} );
 });
```

I got the error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

   8 | export const fetchGreetings = (dispatch) => {
  19 |   dispatch(greetingRequest())
  20 |   fetch('/users')
> 21 |     .then(res => res.json())
  22 |     .then(data => dispatch(greetingReceive(data)))
  23 | }
  24 |
```

Looks like it did go to my redux action file.

This is my express routes file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var data = require('../constant/data')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(data)
});

module.exports = router;
```

I couldn't figure out which part of my project has gone wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like `fetch('/users')` response is not a json itself. Try `res => res.data.json()` instead.

Comment: It's possible that the `app.get(*, ...)` gets the request first, and because it matches `/users` it sends `index.html` which is not a `json` object.